# Add text to base64 string in picture

Tags: javascript, base64

I have a canvas where i capture a signatur (browser app, javascript). I get this signatur in a base64 string and i can download it. This is working fine. Now i want to add a text to the picture (base64-string).

In my research i came across different methodes like watermarks, but this is not working for me and i think it is little to complicated. Is there a possibility or an easy way to add a text to the base64-string?

```
downloadpic: function () {
      var sign = this.getView().byId("Signature");
      var imagetxtb64 = sign.getSigAsJpeg();

      var image = new Image();
      var element = document.createElement('a');

      image.src = imagetxtb64;

      element.setAttribute('href', image.src);
      element.setAttribute('download', 'image');
      element.style.display = 'none';

      element.click();
    }
```

In the `imagetxtb64` variable is the base64-string. Can i modify it by adding some text to it?

#### Update:

I have now the following function:

```
    downloadtext: function () {

    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");


    var sign = this.getView().byId("Signature");
    var imagetxtb64 = sign.getSigAsJpeg();

    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.drawImage(imagetxtb64, 0, 0);

    var randomtxt = "Random Text";
    ctx.font = "30px Arial";
    ctx.strokeText(randomtxt, 10, 50);

    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
    console.log(dataURL);

    var image = new Image();
    var element = document.createElement('a');

    image.src = dataURL;

    element.setAttribute('href', image.src);
    element.setAttribute('download', 'image');
    element.style.display = 'none';

    element.click();

    },
```

i guess with `ctx.drawImage(imagetxtb64, 0, 0);` i load the existing canvas in the new one.

But when I try to execute this i get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(CSSImageValue or HTMLImageElement or SVGImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap or OffscreenCanvas)'

Comment: You could load the Base64 encoded image into a hidden canvas, add text and then export it again

Comment: thanks for your reply. Is there any documentary of working with a hidden canvas? Or do you have experiences with it?

Comment: You can always create a canvas without actually adding it to the document: [Demo Here](https://jsfiddle.net/w752t0hk/)

Comment: thanks for your help! now i have created a hidden canvas with a specific text. This means now i have two canvas. One with the signatur and one with my specific text. Do you know how i can layover the text canvas over the signatur canvas?

Comment: No that's not what I meant. You create a new canvas, load the base64 image data and then write the text on the same canvas.

Comment: Ok. I have updated my post above with my new function. Here i want to load the old canvas in the new one with drawImage(). But here i got a error message.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192718/discussion-between-alfons-alpi-and-nulldev).